# Is there a way to UPLOAD photos/video's to my Google Drive .. but not SYNC?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, upload

I have a lot of photo's and video's I wish to upload to my Google Drive**

I don't want to ***sync*** them, because that means I have a local copy AND a copy in the cloud. (And if I delete the local copy, then it syncs with the cloud and deletes that item from the cloud)

I don't want to BACKUP all of this stuff because that generally means that, if I wish view them in the cloud, i need to RESTORE the data to my local and then view them.

It's like i want to FTP my files up to my Google Drive and access them via a browser.

Can this be done?

---

** If google drive can't do this - is there another option?

Comment: If you don't want to sync, Google Drive is probably not the right service for you. Why not use one of the services specifically for images and videos, like Flickr?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is about installable software. While the client available at the time that this question was created was retired, as of October 2023, there are installable clients for Windows, Mac, Android, iPhone and iPad, so a question like this might be on topic in [su], [apple.se], [android.se] according to the platform corresponding to the app to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can by [whitelisting which folders you want to sync](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375083?hl=en).

Though, I am not aware of any "blacklisting" approach with Google Drive (i.e "*not* sync selected folders").

If you're looking for other solutions, you can try some other services such as [Bitcasa](https://www.bitcasa.com/) or [BackBlaze](http://www.backblaze.com/).

Comment: but this is still *syncing* right? i just want to go *one-way*...

Comment: Then I would suggest using either a backup service with versioning such as Time Machine for OS X, or simply pushing to FTP server with a simple web server running on the front. Maybe you can find a solution in services based on OwnCloud (or installing it yourself). Or just upload manually your files into ordered folders on Google Drive?

Comment: Bitcasa has proven to be quite unreliable [by changing their subscription types and wiping customer data without a proper warning in November 2014](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2014/10/24/bitcasa-pulls-plug-infinite-storage-gives-users-3-weeks-migrate-files-new-system/). I would not recommend their product at all.

Comment: I totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload photos to Google+ (or to picasaweb, alas only if you keep a pre-Google+ account) and then view them on the web. Ditto with Flikr and Smugmug and other photo-sharing sites.

You don't upload via sync to these sites but that sounds like what you want: post, not sync.

After upload, you may delete your local copies.

I'd upload the videos to YouTube. You can choose whether to make them public, or visible only to people who know the URL, or private.

BTW you can upload an unlimited amount of "standard size" photos to Google+, or a limited amount of full size photos for free and pay for more storage if needed. See https://support.google.com/plus/answer/156348?hl=en#